# Order by ignored when using group by on joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write 1 query to display a list of forum threads ordered by the latest post date.

This is quite a simple process getting the data from the database however due to the `joins` and `group by`, the `order by` I wish to use isn't possible.

## Table Structures

*ForumRooms*

```
|  id  |  title  |
|----------------|
|  1   | Room 1  |
|  2   | Room 2  |
```

*ForumThreads*

```
|  id  |  title    |  forum_room_id  |
|------------------|-----------------|
|  1   | Thread 1  |  1              |
|  2   | Thread 2  |  2              |
|  3   | Thread 3  |  1              |
```

*ForumPosts*

```
|  id  |  content  |  forum_thread_id |  post_time  |  user_id  |
|------------------|------------------|-------------|-----------|
|  1   | A post 1  |  1               |  15/02/2015 |  1        |
|  2   | A post 2  |  2               |  16/02/2015 |  2        |
|  3   | A post 3  |  1               |  17/02/2015 |  1        |
|  4   | A post 4  |  1               |  18/02/2015 |  2        |
|  5   | A post 5  |  2               |  19/02/2015 |  1        |
```

## Desired Output

This is the output I'd ideally have, the threads are sorted by the most recent thread post.

```
|  Thread Title |  Last Post User  | Last Post Time  |  Creator User  |
|---------------|------------------|-----------------|----------------| 
|  Thread 2     |  1               |  19/02/2015     |  2             |
|  Thread 1     |  2               |  18/02/2015     |  1             |
```

## The Problem

At the moment I can get everything in 1 query however there is an issue when trying to `ORDER BY ForumPosts.id`, I think this is due to the `GROUP BY` combined with the joins.

This means I have all of the required data but it's not in the order of the latest forum post.

**Current incorrect query**

```
SELECT 
  ForumThreads.title, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ForumPosts.user_id ORDER BY ForumPosts.id ASC), ',', 1),
  MAX(ForumPosts.`post_time`),
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ForumPosts.user_id ORDER BY ForumPosts.id DESC), ',', 1)
FROM
  forumThreads 
  INNER JOIN `ForumRooms` 
    ON ForumThreads.forum_room_id = ForumRooms.id 
  INNER JOIN `ForumPosts` 
    ON ForumThreads.id = ForumPosts.`forum_thread_id` 
WHERE ForumRooms.id = 1 
GROUP BY ForumThreads.id 
ORDER BY ForumPosts.id DESC
```

How can I write a query that will achieve the above desired output?

---

**Update 1**

I've tried implementing the sub query approach as suggested by *Jean-François Savard* but the `ORDER BY a.id` is ignored and it still orders by `ForumTopics.id`

Comment: Why do you need the group by ?  I see no aggregation functionality here, is  it not enough to order by ForumPosts.'post_time' DESC?

Comment: Because then you get multiple posts per thread?

Comment: I see, you only want the last post per thread.

Comment: ORDER BY MAX(ForumPosts.Id) DESC ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a small change to the original query is needed - either add `MAX(ForumPosts.id) AS max_post_id` to your SELECT and then order by that:

```
SELECT 
  ForumThreads.title, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ForumPosts.user_id ORDER BY ForumPosts.id ASC), ',', 1),
  MAX(ForumPosts.`post_time`),
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ForumPosts.user_id ORDER BY ForumPosts.id DESC), ',', 1),
  MAX(ForumPosts.id) AS max_post_id
FROM
  forumThreads 
  INNER JOIN `ForumRooms` 
    ON ForumThreads.forum_room_id = ForumRooms.id 
  INNER JOIN `ForumPosts` 
    ON ForumThreads.id = ForumPosts.`forum_thread_id` 
WHERE ForumRooms.id = 1 
GROUP BY ForumThreads.id 
ORDER BY max_post_id DESC
```

Or you can just alias `MAX(ForumPosts.post_time)` and order by that:

```
SELECT 
  ForumThreads.title, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ForumPosts.user_id ORDER BY ForumPosts.id ASC), ',', 1),
  MAX(ForumPosts.`post_time`) AS max_post_time,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ForumPosts.user_id ORDER BY ForumPosts.id DESC), ',', 1)
FROM
  forumThreads 
  INNER JOIN `ForumRooms` 
    ON ForumThreads.forum_room_id = ForumRooms.id 
  INNER JOIN `ForumPosts` 
    ON ForumThreads.id = ForumPosts.`forum_thread_id` 
WHERE ForumRooms.id = 1 
GROUP BY ForumThreads.id 
ORDER BY max_post_time DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery

```
select * from(
SELECT 
  ForumPosts.id,
  group_concat(ForumThreads.title), 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ForumPosts.user_id ORDER BY ForumPosts.id ASC), ',', 1),
  MAX(ForumPosts.`post_time`),
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ForumPosts.user_id ORDER BY ForumPosts.id DESC), ',', 1)
FROM
  forumThreads 
  INNER JOIN `ForumRooms` 
    ON ForumThreads.forum_room_id = ForumRooms.id 
  INNER JOIN `ForumPosts` 
    ON ForumThreads.id = ForumPosts.`forum_thread_id` 
WHERE ForumRooms.id = 1 
GROUP BY ForumThreads.id) a
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

Comment: Even with the `ORDER BY a.id` it still orders by `ForumThreads.id DESC` for some reason?

Comment: @Silver89 are you sure you want to group by ForumThreads.id ? maybe you want ForumThreads.title ?

Comment: Titles might not be unique though, also the same issue arises?

Comment: @Silver89 Try new query, I think that is what you want.

Comment: `listagg does not exist`

Comment: Wow, I don't know why but for a lap of time I tought you were using Oracle.. Then change listagg for group_concat see edit.

Comment: Result is exactly the same, it's the group by and order by that are causing the issue I think, see updated question?

Comment: @Silver89 You want it ordered by ForumPosts.id, right ?

Comment: @Silver89 I wonder why don't you simply remove the group by clause ?

Comment: Because then you get duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
SELECT a.ThreadTitle, a.LastPostUser, a.LastPostTime, p2.user_id CreatorUser FROM (
    SELECT t.title ThreadTitle, p.user_id LastPostUser, p.post_time LastPostTime, p.forum_thread_id
    FROM (SELECT * FROM ForumPosts ORDER BY post_time DESC) p
    JOIN ForumThreads t ON t.id=p.forum_thread_id
    JOIN ForumRooms r ON t.forum_room_id=r.id
    GROUP BY threadTitle ) a
JOIN (SELECT * FROM ForumPosts GROUP BY forum_thread_id) p2 ON p2.forum_thread_id=a.forum_thread_id 
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: The `LastPostUser` and `CreatorUser` are the same?

Comment: Both are user_id from ForumPosts

Comment: But one is going to be the first post and one is going to be the last post, not the same user?

Comment: You can use "order by 3" or "order by a.LastPostTime", which is in the 3rd place in the SELECT. DESC means descendant sort.